# How to move files from one directory to another in Unity Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, directory, hololens

[here is picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsomx.png)

I am trying to use windows.storage namespace and trying to drop a file in Streaming asset in unity.

Comment: Sorry, [we can't accept images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please [edit] your question and include those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Always use `FileStream` on UWP devices and pass in the correct open methods and Fileshare options. Windows systems seam quite picky when it comes to FileIO

Answer (score 0):

The Unity StreamingAssets folder is read-only and used to store Assets. For specific instructions, please see the Unity official doc: [Application.StreamingAssetsPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html).

Therefore, I suggest you save the file in the [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) and note that source files have read and write permissions.

To move the file from the objects3D folder to the persistentDataPath folder, you can try the following code:

```
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
        var objectPath = KnownFolders.Objects3D.Path;
        string path = Path.Combine(objectPath, "MyFile.txt");
        string targetPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "MyFile.txt");
        using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("test");
        }
        File.Move( path, targetPath);
#endif
```